# Cannot see number of views for question on mobile?

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, views

In the responsive mobile layout, the number of views for a question is not available on the view question page, like it is on desktop:

[image]

I understand that sacrifices have to be made for the mobile template, but it seems like there is actually a decent amount of whitespace between the question title and the question, so there would be plenty of room for displaying views. The views are a really important metric for me because it is an indication of how much attention my question is getting, so I can know if I need to make edits, provide more information, or set a bounty.

Can we get the views to show up on mobile?

Comment: I agree with you: having the number of views shown on mobile would be helpful, I upvoted your question. I would also like to have this feature on the android/iphone apps.

Comment: This question is has never been answered!